# Tomcat 8 how to set jarsToSkip

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

We are using Tomcat 7.0 and we want to switch to tomcat 8. There was a parameter in Tomcat 7.0 `org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip` but it does not work in tomcat 8.0.

Any idea ?!

**Long Story**

Our web application provides some web-services. We used the `webservices-rt-2.3.1.jar` to implement web services. The jar has a `servlet` named `WSServletContainerInitializer` which extends `ServletContainerInitializer` this auto starts by Tomcat. This was not what we wanted, so we used the `org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=webservices-rt-2.3.1.jar` to force Tomcat to skip this jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for the [JarScanFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scan-filter.html) which is new in Tomcat 8. It's much more flexible than the all-encompassing `jarsToSkip` setting in Tomcat 7.

Comment: It helped! I added `<JarScanner><JarScanFilter        pluggabilitySkip="${tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan}, webservices-rt-2.3.1.jar"/></JarScanner>`  and it worked!